# How to input shell command longer than 2047 chars in Alpine Docker container?

Tags: docker, shell, command-line, sh, alpine-linux

I want to execute a long command (with long environment variables) with `sh` in a `alpine` docker container, but the length is limited to 2047 characters.

After starting the container:

```
docker run -it alpine
```

When I paste some long commands (or strings), I can't type more than 2047 characters. How can I increase this limit or execute a long command?

I also checked ARG_MAX

```
getconf ARG_MAX
# 131072
```

Comment: `ARG_MAX` controls how long of a command can be _run_ (after expansions are performed, environment variable space is allocated, etc), not how long of a command can be _entered_. It's a completely different, unrelated thing. (For example, if you run `s='1234567890'`, `"$s"` counts as ten or eleven characters against ARG_MAX -- depending on whether it's a substring or a complete argument -- even though it's only four characters on the command line).

Comment: ...this is presumably a limitation compiled into the shell you're using. You can of course install bash on Alpine instead of using the built-in busybox dash release.